# Run script after changes in X server geometry

Tags: x11, xorg, xrandr

Is there an option to run a given script after the X server geometry is changed (or every invokation of xrandr)?

Comment: Why not renaming xrandr as xrandr.orig and crest your own xrandr that calls xrandr.orig and do some stuff

Comment: Because `apt-get` would not be happy to find that `xrandr` changed on the disk and updates would be stalled.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no builtin way to run a script like this from the core X server, but [it’s possible to write an X client that listens for reconfiguration events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400236/how-to-observe-changes-in-connected-monitors-via-xlib) and runs code, so a window manager or similar application could do this and provide a way for you to configure it to run a script, but without knowing what you're running, it's hard to say if yours does.